# jQuery modification needed in script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Here is a jQuery script for sliding in letters, but how do I remove the last class of "fade out" so that the letters remain at their final position? Here is the demo:

http://blog.waiyanlin.net/example/jquery/flyingtext.html

and here is the script for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.container .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
  $('.container .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "350px"}, 1000);

  var int = setInterval(changeText, 1000);  


  function changeText(){

    var $activeText = $(".container .active-text"); 

    var $nextText = $activeText.next(); 
    if($activeText.next().length == 0) $nextText = $('.container .flying-text:first');

    $activeText.animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
    $activeText.animate({marginLeft: "-100px"});

    $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "350px"}, 500, function() {
      $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                         
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: you mean you don't want the text to hide? and you want to keep it visible?

Comment: yeah but visible at the stationary final postion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely easy, 2 modifications are required. Remove animation, and clear timeout. You should have been able to figure this out yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.container .flying-text').css({opacity:0});
  $('.container .active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "350px"}, 1000);

  var intval = setInterval(changeText, 1000);    

  function changeText() {
    var $activeText = $(".container .active-text"); 
    var $nextText = $activeText.next();

    if ($activeText.next().length == 0) clearInterval(intval);

    $nextText.css({opacity: 0}).addClass('active-text').animate({opacity:1, marginLeft: "350px"}, 500, function(){
      $activeText.removeClass('active-text');                                           
    });
  }
});
```

As per comments, here is a link to the working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8ZGA/

Comment: Just realised that you are naming the interval object 'int' as well. You should probably avoid using types as variable names, try 'intval' instead.

Comment: Amazing. You help someone, with code that works fine, and they don't even thank you. Here's a jsfiddle with the exact same code, working perfectly, as described. http://jsfiddle.net/Q8ZGA/

Comment: @Kashmir Kashir Srinagar I have tested the code myself too, it works. Only the animation is fast, probably due to the fact that he needed to test it a bit faster and forgot to put it back. just change the `400` value at the end, back to `4000` and use his code after he changed the variable name from `int` to `intval`

Comment: @christian, i didnt mean that, n thnks for that code n ur help

Comment: got it i twas be being wrng at some point,,,@christaian, thks buddy,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you need to leave text after animation. In this case remove this string:

```
$activeText.animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
$activeText.animate({marginLeft: "-100px"});
```

Because you are fading it out.

Code (without interval):  http://jsfiddle.net/uedt6/4/

Comment: i tried that but then the text slides back to where it came from, but i want it to stay at it its final place n also the animation repeats itself ovr n ovr again,,

Comment: So, you need to slide left and fade in all 3 words, than fade out all 3 words and repeat it? Am I right?

Comment: i need the text to slide from the left to the right , then stop the animation with the words at ttheir final position, i.e towards the right

Comment: Can you describe what is your goal? :)

Comment: i need the text to slide from the left to the right , then stop the animation with the words at ttheir final position, i.e towards the right